# How do I solve this inequality problem from the 2010 AMC?

Tags: inequality, interval-arithmetic

The length of the interval of solutions of the inequality $a \le 2x + 3 \le b$ is $10$. What is $b - a$?

$\mathrm{(A)}\ 6 \qquad \mathrm{(B)}\ 10 \qquad \mathrm{(C)}\ 20 \qquad \mathrm{(D)}\ 30 \qquad \mathrm{(E)}\ 40$

I looked at the [solutions](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2010_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_11) and saw that $x$ has to be separated and then the two sides subtracted are equal to 10. I do not understand what is meant by the "interval of solutions" and why $x$ is separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution of an inequation is of the form $p \le x \le q $. So the length of the interval is then $ q -p$. Here if we keep x in the middle  then $ p = (a-3)/2 , q = (b-3)/2 $. Thus then the length in this case $(b-a)/2 = 10$. Thus the answer is 20.